# How to use dotty in scala project?

Tags: scala, sbt, dotty

I am working on a Scala project that I run using `sbt`. I want to use union types which is provided by `dotty`. I am having trouble in using `dotty` in my project.

I did this:

- Added `./projects/plugins.sbt` and `./projects/build.properties` with content as mentioned in [sbt-dotty](https://github.com/lampepfl/sbt-dotty).
- Added `./projects/scalafix.sbt` and a configuration file
  `./.scalafix.conf` with content `scalafixEnabled in ThisBuild := true` in it. This is provided in [sbt-scalafix](https://scalacenter.github.io/scalafix/#sbt-scalafix)

Now if I compile the project, I get a huge list of `Migration Warning`s and errors like `Member Not Found Error`, `Ambiguous overload`, and ends with `java.lang.AssertionError: no TypeBounds allowed`. Is correcting each of these errors the only way to avoid these?

The project was running fine (with scalaVersion := 2.12.1) before making these changes. Can anyone please help me in making it work?

**Edit:** `sbtVersion = 0.13.13`

Comment: Can you provide your SBT version?

Comment: @AkiLegaspi it's 0.13.13. Added this to question as well.

Comment: My impression is that the entirety of the Dotty ecosystem, including `scalafix` is very much in beta and I would be very surprised if `scalafix` was able to successfully migrate your codebase without manual intervention.

Comment: @badcook: Indeed. The fact that the two projects are developed by the same people, and that Dotty is used to try out new ideas for Scala is certainly suggestive, but at the end of the day, those two are two different programming languages, and you need to decide which one of the two you want to write your code in. If you write your code in Scala, compile it with Scala. If you want to compile your code with Dotty, you need to write it in Dotty, not Scala.

Comment: @JörgWMittag see my answer

Answer (score 4):

Dotty is currently in an experimental stage (pre-alpha, no public release at the time of writing). The fact that you get compilation errors means the following:

- Your setup to compile your project with sbt & dotty is probably correct (that answers the question?)
- Your code base might trigger new bugs in dotty

StackOverflow is not the correct place to discuss bugs in unreleased software. If you manage to minimize your issue please report it on the [dotty issue tacker](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues) (or come chat [gitter](https://gitter.im/lampepfl/dotty)). If you are interested in hacking on a compiler there are also plenty of opportunities in these early stages, external contributors are always very welcome!

---

Even if it's not part of your question I feel obliged to address @JörgWMittag comment. Dotty is not a new programming language. The long-term goal is to be able to cross compile the majority of the Scala ecosystem with both compiler, as it's currently the case with Scala 2.10/2.11/2.12. Dotty itself is an example of such project, every test is run with a version of compiler compiled by `scalac` (currently the default), and with a bootstrapped version of the compiler (`dotty` compiled with `dotty`).

In addition, a [community-build](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty-community-build) infrastructure is currently being setup. It's a repository to gather (forks of) open source Scala projects that can be cross compile with `scalac`/`dotty`, which serves as an addition test infrastructure for the compiler.